# PDF inner links not working iphone webview

Tags: iphone

I am Using pdf in my application .i am loading PDF in webView .In that PDF i have index as a first page click on list item it should go that particular page and in that PDF for every page top option is there clock on that it should go first page .how can i solve this problem .help out me
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code 
it may help you
https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Comment: i have not made through CGPDF.... so can u please tell me where exactly u found the way to open the links in pdf on WebView....

Comment: i'm trying to figure this out as well..i'm using Titanium mobile unfortunately so this wont directly help me. I'd have to create a plugin out of this

Answer (score 2):

i am loading PDF in webView .In that PDF i have index as a first page click on list item it should go that particular page and in that PDF for every page top option is there clock on that it should go first page

check its code it will help u...

im using it my app

https://github.com/vfr/Reader